# How do I change GitLab <title>?

Tags: gitlab

I've looked and looked and can't find it..I want to change the page title

```
<title>GitLab</title>
```

to include more information.  I can't seem to find anywhere to do this as i've scoured github and don't see any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you consider a page like [`app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml), you see:

```
!!! 5
%html{ lang: "en"}
  = render "layouts/head"      <=====
  %body.ui_basic.login-page
    = render "layouts/flash"
    .container
      .content
        %center
          %h1 GitLab
```

That means the `<head>` part of the html result is generated by [`app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml):

```
%head
  %meta{charset: "utf-8"}
  %title
    = "#{title} | " if defined?(title)
    GitLab
```

That is where that GitLab comes from.

As explained in this [haml reference document](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#using_haml), the title is modified with `@title`:

```
# file: app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = "Teen Wolf"
  end
end
```

For instance, the GitLab source '[`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb#L9)' modifies the title.

But I don't see any way to put as a parameter the *default* title which is put when a controller doesn't define a title.
So you may have to modify directly that `_head.html.haml` file.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fork for gitlab just for titles.

https://github.com/anezi/gitlabhq

You can check the diff: https://github.com/anezi/gitlabhq/compare/gitlabhq:6-3-stable...6-3-stable

Answer (score 0):

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml

change your file at line 2.

```html
- page_description brand_title unless page_description
-# site_name = "Gitlab"
- site_name = "ChainMaker"
```