# How do I add an "about us" page in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I'm hosting GitLab on a server. I need to add an "about us" page. How can I do that? I'm using the GitLab Community Edition on a Debian server.

An about us" page is compulsory in Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wiki page on your GitLab installation and then edit the template files to hardcode a link to that page in the footer or in the header.

You can find a detailed guide on how to changed the template files at https://kovah.me/en/customize-gitlab-installation/. Basically you have to edit the `.html.haml` files in `$GITLAB_ROOT/app/views/layouts/`.

See also: [How do I change GitLab <title>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945890/how-do-i-change-gitlab-title)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to add an about page in the [wiki](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki) associated to your GitLab project.

You can reference it when adding a [welcome message to the sign-in page](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/customization/welcome_message.html).